# How to output contents of tags <div> in listbox

Tags: c#, html, parsing

On the form is textbox in which the site address is entered(http://localhost.com/index.html).
I want that in listbox contents of tags  were output. 
How it can be made?

Comment: You need to clarify what you want here, that doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: Do you need to know how to add the contents of a textbox to a listbox? Or are you having a problem with the way it looks when the URL gets in that list?

Answer (score 0):

The [Html Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output tag content (HTML), you can do this on the client side, because each parent node can reference its entire child content via the innerHTML or outerHTML properties.  This returns the entire contents as a string, which you can assign its contents:

var a = document.getElementById("Test1");
document.getElementById("TextBox").value = a.outerHTML;